# Java Simple Program Does Not Run

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm learning Java and I wanted to test this program in Eclipse:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class apples{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        tuna tunaObject = new tuna();
        System.out.println("Enter name of first gf here: ");
        String temp = input.nextLine();
        tunaObject.setName(temp);
        tunaObject.saying();
    }
}
```

And this is the Class that I'm working with:

```
public class tuna{
    private String girlsName;
    public void setName(name) {
        girlsName = name;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return girlsName;
    }
    public void saying(){
        System.out.println("Your first gf was %s",getName());
    }
}
```

But as soon as I run it, I got these three errors:

> Syntax error, insert "... VariableDeclaratorId" to complete
>   FormalParameterList   tuna.java   /Bucky/src  line 3  Java Problem
>
> The method println(String) in the type PrintStream is not applicable
>   for the arguments (String, String)    tuna.java   /Bucky/src  line 10 Java
>   Problem
>
> The method setName() in the type tuna is not applicable for the
>   arguments (String)    apples.java /Bucky/src  line 9  Java Problem

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method setName() in the type tuna is not applicable for the arguments (String)**

**at apples.main(apples.java:9)**

I have no idea about these errors, why they happens and how to fix them!

So can you help me with that...

Comment: You're missing a type for `name`, and you're confusing `println` with `printf`.

Comment: I would recommend changing your class names to be uppercase. (Apples and Tuna)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace  your setName function with this :

```
public void setName(String name) {
    girlsName = name;
}
```

You forgot add param type.

Answer (score 1):

Java is a strongly typed language, you are missing the type of name while defining method. So this:

```
 public void setName(name) {
```

Should change to:

```
public void setName(String name) {
                    ^^^^^^
```

Here you are defining setter method with `name` as parameter of type `String`.

Answer (score 1):

In your tuna class you setName method should be

```
public void setName(String name)
```

and your print statement in your saying method should be a printf

```
System.out.printf()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a data type to the parameter in setName method.
Replace

```
    public void setName(name) {
            girlsName = name;
    }
```

With

`public void setName(String name) {
        girlsName = name;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? There is multiple syntax errors.

1. Put type for your argument in setName() > setName(**String** name)
2. Write **printf** with your current code

> System.out.printf("Your first gf was %s", getName());

This should clear all errors.